# MySQL stored procedure select query fails

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, random, unique

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `temp` $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GenerateUniqueValue`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `GenerateUniqueValue`(IN tableName VARCHAR(255),IN columnName VARCHAR(255)) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE uniqueValue VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE newUniqueValue VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT "";
    WHILE LENGTH(uniqueValue) = 0 DO
        SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1)
                ) INTO @newUniqueValue;
        SET @rcount = -1;
        SET @query=CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rcount FROM  ',tableName,' WHERE ',columnName,'  like ''',newUniqueValue,'''');
        PREPARE stmt FROM  @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    IF @rcount = 0 THEN
            SET uniqueValue = @newUniqueValue ;
        END IF ;
    END WHILE ;
    SELECT uniqueValue;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I wrote this procedure for getting a unique value in a table. At random times, it is returning a duplicate value. The select query returns no results for the existing criteria. Not sure where I am missing

Comment: You don't seem to be inserting anything into this table. Are you sure the previous values are actually there? Also, `SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1)` is wrong. The string is 35 characters long, so it should be `RAND()*35`. Also, MySQL rounds up values with a fractional part of 0.5 or more, so if you want to select each character with equal probability, try `SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*35+0.5, 1)`. (Or use `FLOOR()`, which will make your code look a bit more sensible.)

Comment: I am calling this procedure before each insert. The flow is, getting unique value, inserting it into the table. I have tested with following code,

String query="CALL GenerateUniqueValue('test','UniqueValue')";
     for(int i=0;i<50000;i++) {      
      rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
      if(rs.next()) {
       stmt1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test VALUES('"+gsin+"')");
       System.out.println(i+":"+gsin);
      }
     }

Answer (score -1):

```sql
DELIMITER $$
USE `temp` $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GenerateUniqueValue`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `GenerateUniqueValue`(IN tableName VARCHAR(255),IN columnName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE uniqueValue VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE newUniqueValue VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT "";
    WHILE LENGTH(uniqueValue) = 0 DO
        SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1),
                SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', RAND()*34+1, 1)
                ) INTO @newUniqueValue;
        SET @rcount = -1;
        SET @query=CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rcount FROM  ',tableName,' WHERE ',columnName,'  like ''',@newUniqueValue,'''');
        PREPARE stmt FROM  @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    IF @rcount = 0 THEN
            SET @query=CONCAT('insert into  ',tableName,' ( ',columnName,' ) values (''',@newUniqueValue,''')');
            PREPARE stmt FROM  @query;
         EXECUTE stmt;
         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
            SET uniqueValue = @newUniqueValue ;
        END IF ;
    END WHILE ;
SELECT @query;
    END
```